# Custom Telemetry Processor not loading

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I've written a small Telemetry Processor to filter out some HTTP 404 which are not an issue for my application. I've been following [Microsoft's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#filtering) on this process.

I have created a new class implementing ITelemetryProcessor and setup the constructor and process function.

```
namespace My_App
{
    class WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

        // Link processors to each other in a chain.
        public WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            this.Next = next;
        }

        public void Process(ITelemetry item)
        {
            var request = item as RequestTelemetry;

            if (request != null &&
            request.ResponseCode.Equals("404", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // To filter out an item, just terminate the chain:
                return;
            }
            // Send everything else:
            this.Next.Process(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added a new line to my ApplicationInsights.config under `<TelemetryProcessors>`

```
<Add Type="My_App.WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter, My_App" />
```

Upon starting my program I see the following message recorded in AI in Visual Studio.

```
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'My_App.WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter, My_App' was not found. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
```

I suspect the issue lies with the line in config. Microsoft's docs don't seem to detail exactly what that line should contain. My guess based on MS example is the namespaced path to the filter class and the namespace for my application.

Comment: The type should contain the namespace followed by class name (i.e `My_App.WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter`) and then the assembly name so make sure your app is `My_App`. If this still doesn't work, how about initializing the `TelemetryProcessor` directly instead of using the config, as shown [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Telemetry-Processors:-Sampling-and-Metrics-Stream#using-custom-telemetry-processor) i.e `builder.Use((next) => new WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter(next))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out my problem was two parts.

The way I was declaring my telemetry processor was incorrect and [degant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43925876/698026) corrected that.

The second issue I found was that a custom telemetry processors' Process method will never be called unless you have `InstrumentationKey` set in your config. Leaving it blank while developing locally won't work.

There was an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/344) on the Application Insights Github for this which has been [resolved](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/pull/604).

Answer (score 5):

You probably forgot to mark the class `public` so the type isn't being found. Update your telemetry processor as `public`:

```
public class WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
```

Also, the correct way to specify the type includes the fully qualified name of your telemetry processor followed by the assembly name. So in your example the assembly name must be `My_App`

```
<!-- Fully qualified type name, assembly name: -->
<Add Type="My_App.WebJobQueuesDependencyFilter, My_App" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I hadn't specified my class as public previously. But I'm seeing the same error after adding it in. I've confirmed that "My_App" is the value listed for the AssemblyTitle attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs. I tried adding my processor through the code. I can see that it adds my class in the active configuration, but don't see my Process function run when logging requests and events. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ah! My apologies, I needed to use the assembly name from the project settings (with spaces instead of underscores). It's now detecting it correctly. It's still doesn't seem to be running through my processor, but that's likely a separate issue. I'll mark this question as solved and open a new question if I can't get that working still.

Comment: Found a solution. For anyone else with this issue `InstrumentationKey` must be set in your config for filters to run. Leaving it blank while developing locally won't work. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/344

Comment: @Dracs you are a life saver... really you should put this up as an answer (and I will upvote it).

Comment: @OhadSchneider, good idea. Added it as a seperate answer for better visibility of that issue.

Comment: @Dracs nice, upvoted. Don't forget to accept your own answer :)